# Fetching content from subpages of current UiD

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

I'm developing my first site in TYPO3, currently I have a structure that looks like:

```
Page1
      subpage1
      subpage2
      subpage folder -> with images

Page2
      subpage1
      subpage2
      subpage3 folder -> with images
```

What I want to do is load content from subpages of Page1 into my subpage(say images from folder would part of slider, subpage1 would be main content and subpage2 would be sidebar content.

The idea is to use templavoila and map it via Typoscript object.

Now the problem I'm facing is, I have no idea how to fetch content from current UID subpages. How would I do that in the mentioned context?

I'm not asking for a done solution, just point me in the right direction or show similar example etc.

Thanks. :)

Comment: could you rephrase ... the question is clear but the context not ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to get the list of pids first and then you can use the `CONTENT` TS object. Properly you can use the `stdWrap.cObject` property to generate your list of page ids just inside the `CONTENT` object.

Post a comment of you need an example.

Comment: please do supply example !